# How to add linebreaks automatically?

Tags: line-breaking, margins

I want to have latex automatically add line breaks to long sequences of characters that do not contain spaces. For instance:

`...................................................................................................................................................................................`

into

`...................................
...................................
...................................
...................................
...................................
.....`

I also need to be able to manipulate the color of some of the periods using `\textcolor{red}{.}`, for instance. I am aware of the `seqsplit` package but can't seem to change fonts, sizes, colors of the text within it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Your question is not very clear. Please ilustrate it with small, complete document with `\documentclass{...}` on the begin and `\end{document}` on the end, which will demonstrate your problem. In normal circumstance LaTeX break lines to the specified text width.

Comment: With respect to the 'linebreaks', are you looking for things like `\parbox` or the `minipage` environment? These are covered in introductory materials.  Or, does your reference to the `seqsplit` package mean those dots are all characters of one long 'word'?  I think more information is needed at this point....

Answer (score 3):

All you need will be satisfied with `seqsplit` and `minipage` or `parbox`. see the code below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{seqsplit}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{.7\textwidth}
\seqsplit{%
agtcctttggggatctgtccactcctgatgctgttatgggcaaccctaaggtgaaggctc%
atggcaagaaagtgctcggt{\textcolor{red}{\LARGE g}}cctttagtgatggcctggctcacctggacaacctcaagg%
gcacctttgccacactgagtgagctgcactgtgacaagctgcacgtggatcctgagaact%
taataaaaaacatttattttcattgc}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to automatically add line breaks in a section, you can change the line width by using `\parbox{<linewidth>}{<content>}`. If you want to change the color of some of the periods you just have to use what you've figured out for that.